# Modify html of rails `link_to` helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails has the `link_to` helper, and I'm aware that its output is determined by the ActionView::Helper::UrlHelper` method, but what is an easy and simple way to modify the behavior or rather make a different helper that would work similarly, the default behavior would output something similar to:

```
<a href="/blah" class="my_link">go to blah</a>
```

So say I wanted to have a `<span>` inside the `<a>` like so:

```
<a href="/blah" class="my_link"><span>go to blah</span></a>
```

If I wanted to create the helper, I'm aware that I should probably put in in my `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` file but how would I construct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

link_to takes a block. You can do just about anything you want in there.

Answer (score 0):

Helper is just normal function, there is nothing magic about it:

```
def my_link_to
  put your code here
end
```